# Where are footer variable defined in opencart?

Tags: php, variables, opencart, footer

I am trying to edit the link to one of the items in the footer in the following tpl file:

```
<?php if ($informations) : ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">

        <div class="module clearfix">
            <h3 class="modtitle"><?php echo $text_information; ?></h3>
            <div  class="modcontent" >
                <ul class="menu">
                    <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

it seems that they are looping through an array i guess where it says foreach ($informations as $information) { ?, where should i find $informations variable or how can i access the content of these variables?

Answer (score 0):

The `$informations` defined in this file:

```
catalog/controller/common/footer.php
```

line 25, Opencart 2.2.0.0

this part:

```
    $data['informations'] = array();

    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            $data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

> how can i access the content of these variables?

When you create or edit an information page in admin panel, there's a checkbox labeled `Bottom`, if you check this option, this information page will be in `$informations` array.

If you trying to change a link via code, you can modify above code:

```
    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            if($result['title'] == 'About Us'){
                $link = "myCustomLink";
            } else {
                $link = $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id']);
            }
            $data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $link
            );
        }
    }
```

Or by information id:

```
if($result['information_id'] == 4){
```